# Composer version constraints: How stable is patch?

Tags: composer-php

For a composer version constraint how stable is [the "`patch`" <sup>Composer versions</sup>](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#version) in terms of the order in the [stability-flags](https://igor.io/2013/02/07/composer-stability-flags.html).

Is it *`stable`*? Where does it fit into the order?

The [*`minimum-stability`* setting](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability) does not list it:

> Available options (in order of stability) are `dev`, `alpha`, `beta`, `RC`, and `stable`.

From common sense I would say that a *patch* is a patched stable version so I would consider it stable.

But would a version requirement of `3.1.3-patch1`  satisfy a *`minimum-stability`*-Setting of `stable`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Patch is considered stable. Take a look at the code in [`VersionSelectorTest.php`](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/4cd6eabdba7674fa63d4b71ff4791752a5e99adf/tests/Composer/Test/Package/Version/VersionSelectorTest.php#L233):

```
// real version, is dev package, stability, expected recommendation, [branch-alias]
array('3.1.2-patch', false, 'stable', '^3.1')
```